# template type deduction: comparisons between different template types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a templated struct:

```
template <typename T, typename T2>
struct MyStruct {};
```

and I want to determine if some type is a "MyStruct" (I don't care what the template parameters are).

```
template <typename OtherType, typename TestingType, typename = std::enable_if< IsMyStruct<TestingType>::value, TestingType>::type >
struct OtherStruct {};
```

How do I write `IsMyStruct`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct IsMyStruct : std::false_type { };

template <typename T1,typename T2>
struct IsMyStruct<MyStruct<T1,T2> > : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: The normal idiom is to inherit from `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` respectively, just as a side-note.